# How to click the image link by selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I have the following html page source, and I tried to click the image by xpath/cssselector. none can work, could you help me to find the issue with my code? I use IE9.

```
<pretable border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700">
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2" width="120">
          <a href="#" onclick="oCMenu.m['top1'].b.moveIt(8,60); oCMenu.showsub('top1'); " 
            onclick="return false" class="FontNormal">
           <img border="0" src="images/shim.gif" width="112" height="73"></a></td>  
       </tr>
  </pretable>
```

my code is:

```
    ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/table/tr[1]/td/a[@class='FontNormal']/img[@src='images
     /shim.gif']")).click();

    ieDriver.findElement(By.cssselector("class='FontNormal'")).click();
```

Answer (score 3):

With the available DOM Structure we can always go with CSS Selector.

CSS Selectors

```
css=a[href='images/shim.gif']
css=a[href*='shim.gif']
```

Then Perform

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='images/shim.gif']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='shim.gif']")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to provide a full xpath and yet it does not match up with your html provided.

'table' is not the same as 'pretable', and you don't need to supply the full path anyway. Instead just try this for your xpath:

```
XPath("//a[@class='FontNormal']")
```

Here, xpath will search for **any** link with the class 'FontNormal' attached. If there is only one, this will select your element. If there is more you may need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

First write proper xpath to identify that webelement where you want to perform click operation

```
  driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//img[@ src='images/shim.gif']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
element(By.xpath('//html/table/tr[1]/td/a[@class='FontNormal']/img[@src='images
     /shim.gif']')).click();
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) with [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firepath/) for Mozilla Firefox. This will automatically generate xpath for you.

```
Webelement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("*xpath here*");
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

click on image link by using xpath.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/static/images/image_name.png')]")).click();

You can change the image path depending on your image source.