# How to click on an image/link using Selenium WebDriver (Java)

Tags: java, image, selenium, button, click

I am on this website and I am trying to click on Mass_based Search using the selenium webDriver (in Java): 
http://mmcd.nmrfam.wisc.edu/

The HTML code for the image/button is:

```
<img name="navbut4" src="http://mmcd.nmrfam.wisc.edu/cq-4.gif" onmouseover="glow('navbut4', 'tool4on')" onmouseout="glow('navbut4', 'tool4off')" border="0" alt="MASS_based search" onclick="cqmass()">
```

My attempted solution is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://mmcd.nmrfam.wisc.edu/cq-4.gif']")).click();
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. 
Any ideas?

Edit: I've looked at the possible duplicate question but none of the solutions on that website have worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to click the image link by selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824614/how-to-click-the-image-link-by-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Your xpath seem not correct, I am using the tool of chrome (f12) and got the xpath like this: `//*[@id="masss"]/tbody/tr/td/img`. Give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your element is in iframe So before click first switch to iframe

like

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='leftFrame']")));
```

and then perform the click

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td > img[name='navbut4']")).click();
```

And you have to come back from that iframe to proceed for other actions other then that iframe

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

The complete code will be like

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://mmcd.nmrfam.wisc.edu/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.switchTo().frame("leftFrame");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td > img[name='navbut4']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The element `Mass_based Search` is located witin an `iframe` with `id` as `leftFrame`. So we have to switch to the `iframe` first.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("leftFrame");
```

Now we can identify the element `MASS_based search` through the `name` locator and call `click()` as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("navbut4")).click();
```

Once you complete the jobs on the `iframe` to come back to the `Top Window` of the page you have to use:

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Here is the working code block:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q45226198_frame_element 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://mmcd.nmrfam.wisc.edu/");
        driver.switchTo().frame("leftFrame"); 
        driver.findElement(By.name("navbut4")).click();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.